# ionic2 Google map streetview not loading the image when run in any iPhone device

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I am not getting the image of street view of google map when loading the image in src of `<img>` tag in ionic2. It is working fine in android device but in iPhone, it is giving the error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Following is the code :

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x200&location=28.68627380000001,77.22178310000004&key=<API_KEY>”/>
```

In the above line of code

```
<API_KEY>
```

is the Api key.

Why is it not showing in iPhone device?

Comment: is there any error on network ?

Comment: i assume you replaced the api_key with your registered api_key

Answer (score 3):

you need give api_key from google.
use this site :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key